# Simultaneously solution of four nonlinear ODE differential equations in MATLAB???

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I want to solve the four nonlinear ODE differential equations simultaneously in MATLAB.
and I must tell that my unknown function is a matrix so how can I solve these equation in Matlab???
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you are looking for help with the code then complete problem formulation with some info on the equations and their known initial conditions would help. Is there a particular solver you have to use like RK45?